# script linux mongodb Error SyntaxError: Unexpected [

Tags: linux, bash, mongodb

I try to write script to remove collection in mongodb and import data to mongodb.

Here my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env mongo
var mongodb = new Mongo().getDB("mydb")
mongodb.getCollection("test").remove({})
if [ "$1" = 1 ];
then
        mongoimport -d mydb-c test --type csv --file data_1.csv --headerline
else
        mongoimport -d mydb-c test --type csv --file data_2.csv --headerline
fi
```

When i run script i got this error:  **E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ at ./import.sh:4
failed to load: ./import.sh**

But when I run this

```
#!/usr/bin/env mongo
    var mongodb = new Mongo().getDB("mydb")
    mongodb.getCollection("test").remove({})
```

or

```
if [ "$1" = 1 ];
    then
            mongoimport -d mydb-c test --type csv --file data_1.csv --headerline
    else
            mongoimport -d mydb-c test --type csv --file data_2.csv --headerline
    fi
```

It works fine!

Anybody can specify where my script wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are trying to use two interpreters, one for mongo and one for shell. You can only use one interpreter for shell script.

For your use can you can use the [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) syntax. Try to run the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash 
mongo << __HERE__
var mongodb = new Mongo().getDB("mydb")
mongodb.getCollection("test").remove({})
__HERE__
if [ "$1" = 1 ];
    then
            mongoimport -d mydb-c test --type csv --file data_1.csv --headerline
    else
            mongoimport -d mydb-c test --type csv --file data_2.csv --headerline
    fi
```